# Request validation turned off doesn't work on MVC pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, request-validation

My web application contains both WebForm page and MVC Views.

In my root web.config i have the following code

`<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />`

And in my web.config for my Views folder i have this code

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />

 <pages validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.
ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage,
 System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc,
 Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

Validation is then turned off on my web form pages but not my MVC Views. I want to turn of request validation for every page so doing it at the controller level is not a solution for me.

Any ideas why this is not working on my MVC Views? The only thing i can find online is to turn the validation mode to 2.0 and set validateRequest to false which i have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

Add `ValidateInput` with `EnableValidation` to `false` in `global` filters.

In   `FilterConfig.cs`

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {

            ValidateInputAttribute noValidate = new ValidateInputAttribute(false);
            filters.Add(noValidate);
        }
```